# Is there a event invoked when a block's width changes?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call my code when the width of the block I listen to changes. How to?

`onresize` is invoked only when the size of the window changes.

Comment: What is causing it to change? answer is no.

Comment: No, there isn't. But you can define a custom event.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you mentioned, there is no `resize` event for elements on the page, just for [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize).

You can however use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect changes in an element:

```js
const foo = document.querySelector('#foo');

let oldWidth =  window.getComputedStyle(foo).getPropertyValue('width');
const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(mutation => {
    if (mutation.target === foo &&
      mutation.attributeName === 'style' &&
      oldWidth !== foo.style.width) {
        foo.textContent = 'Width changed from ' +
          oldWidth + ' to ' + foo.style.width;
        oldWidth = foo.style.width;
    }
  });
});

// configure the observer, just look for attribute changes:
const config = {
  attributes: true
};

// start observing
observer.observe(foo, config);

// change the width after a second so we can detect it
setTimeout(() => {
  foo.style.width = '150px';
}, 1000);
```

```css
#foo {
  border: 2px solid #f30;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: width 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">foo</div>
```

With a little more work you can create a function that will add a custom event to the element you want to detect width changes on:

```js
const addWidthChangeEvent = function(element) {
  let oldWidth =  window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('width');
  const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    mutations.forEach(mutation => {
      if (mutation.target === element &&
        mutation.attributeName === 'style' &&
        oldWidth !== element.style.width) {
          oldWidth = element.style.width;
          element.dispatchEvent(new Event('widthChange'));
      }
    });
  });

  // configure the observer, just look for attribute changes:
  const config = {
    attributes: true
  };

  observer.observe(element, config);
};

const foo = document.getElementById('foo');

// add the new widthChange event to foo
addWidthChangeEvent(foo);

// add a listener for the new event
foo.addEventListener('widthChange', event => {
  foo.textContent = foo.style.width;
}, false);


const randomInt = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

// change the width every 2 seconds
setInterval(() => {
  let newWidth = randomInt(4, 30) * 10;
  foo.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
}, 2000);
```

```css
#foo {
  border: 2px solid #f30;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: width 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">foo</div>
```

Comment: MutationObserver does not observe width change caused by css class. http://jsfiddle.net/4mf8h63r/ Although class change itself can be observed, classes that affect an element's size may be added to elements other than the observed element itself.

Answer (score 14):

An option can be to use [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver):

Observes all width changes.

**JS**:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

var observer = new window.ResizeObserver(entries => 
   console.log(entries[0].contentRect.width));

   observer.observe(foo);
}
```

[Stackblitz in Angular](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-resizeobserver-demo)

Comment: Back when I originally wrote my answer, the `ResizeObserver` didn't exist. As of August 2020, it [appears to be supported in most major browsers now](https://caniuse.com/?search=ResizeObserver).

Comment: This also give the warning: "Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead."

Answer (score 0):

There's no default event provided by browser when the width of your element is changing. However, just like [@Leo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032492/leo) mentioned, you can register and trigger your own event.

There are 3 steps you have to:

1. Register a custom event
2. Bind your element with the custom event
3. Trigger the event when you resize the element

The sample code is here:

#### HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="square"></div>
</body>
```

#### JS

```
$(function() {
  var $square = $('.square');

  // Register a custom event and bind an event handler on it
  $square.on('square.resize', function() {
    console.log('Square is resized!');
  });    

  // Trigger that event when you change the square size
  function resizeSquare() {
    $square.width($square.width() + 10);
    $square.height($square.height() + 10);
    $square.trigger('square.resize');
  }

  // Anytime you resize the square, it will trigger 'square.resize' event
  // In this example, I am using setInverval() to resize the square, but you could
  // change it into any ways you like
  setInterval(resizeSquare, 1000);

});
```

You may check here for [CodePen Live Demo](http://codepen.io/kavare/pen/PqwerK)